# how does "multiply(arr, n-1)*arr[n-1]" work?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have this problem on freeCodeCamp as I'm learning JavaScript.
I'm trying to understand this block of code.

```
  function multiply(arr, n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return multiply(arr, n-1)*arr[n-1];
    }
  }console.log(multiply([2,2,4],3));
```

As a whole, I understand what this code above does. But not this line below.

```
multiply(arr, n-1)*arr[n-1];
```

There's already a about post this specific problem here, but I have read all of the comments and I did not understand.

What I don't understand specifically is `(arr, n-1)`. Exactly what does that do? The rest of the line I can understand after a long time thinking, it's just that little piece that I can't make sense of.

Comment: They're arguments for the function `multiply`. The function is recursive.

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't understand specifically is "(arr, n-1)". Exactly what does that do?

This is the argument list for the function call of the `multiply()` function. You cannot understand this in isolation because it belongs to the function call.

In other words, the *syntactic element* is *not* `(arr, n-1)`, it is `multiply(arr, n-1)`.

A *parameter* is kind of like a "hole" that you leave in a function *definition*. Parameters allow you to make functions re-usable in different contexts.

For example, a function like this:

```ecmascript
function doubleTheValueSix() {
  return 2 * 6;
}
```

is not very useful because it can be used for only one very specific thing. However, we can make it more useful by *parameterizing* it:

```ecmascript
function doubleAnyArbitraryValue(n) {
  return 2 * n;
}
```

is much more useful. Here, `n` is called the *parameter* and `(n)` is called the [*parameter List*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-parameter-lists). In this case, there is only one parameter in the parameter list, but there can be arbitrary many, including – as we have seen above – zero.

An *argument* is what you pass to a function *call* to "fill in" the "hole" left by the parameter in the function definition.

So, in this code here:

```ecmascript
doubleAnyArbitraryValue(42)
```

The literal `42` is the *argument* which gets *bound* to the *parameter* `n` inside the function body of `doubleAnyArbitraryValue`. In other words, everywhere `n` appears in the function body, it gets replaced with `42`.

So, in this case, `42` is the *argument* and `(42)` is the [*argument list*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-argument-lists).

What this means in your particular code snippet is the following:

1. Look up the name `multiply` in the local scope. It could be a `function` defined in the local scope (or in an enclosing scope), a `const`, a `let`, or a `var` defined in the local scope (or in an enclosing scope).
2. Call the object you found in step #1, passing the result of evaluating the expressions in the argument list as arguments:

   1. Evaluate the expression `arr` (which essentially means: look up the name `arr` in the local scope; it could be a `const`, a `let`, or a `var` defined in the local scope (or in an enclosing scope)).
   2. Evaluate the expression `n-1`:

      1. Look up the name `n` in the local scope; it could be a `const`, a `let`, or a `var` defined in the local scope (or in an enclosing scope).
      2. Apply the [*Binary Arithmetic Subtraction Operator `-`*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-subtraction-operator-minus) to the result of step 2.1.1 and the [*Numeric Literal*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-primary-expression-literals) `1`.

You can find the details about how function calls work in [subsection 13.3.6 *Function Calls*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-calls) of the [*ECMAScript Language Specification*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/). (Note, the version I linked to is the *Living Document* which always shows the current state of the *next* release, but that doesn't matter in this case – how function calls work fundamentally hasn't changed since ECMAScript was still called *LiveScript* in 1995 and even before that when it was still called *Mocha*.)